# Best way to store raster data in a compressed format and keep its metadata in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, compression

I am looking for an efficient way to reduce the size of raster files but still keep their metadata in order to alter their style and have them show the appropriate values.

The files that we are using are usually .tiff and .flt. While the individual files may not be large, the accumulation as the project goes on proves to be a burden on a hard drive. Therefore, we tend to need several hard drives and we would like to minimize this number as much as possible.

I have attempted to use geopackage but find it difficult to use as the extent is overwritten each time and never seems to keep all the data. The geopackage also has to be added as individual files otherwise, the data can not be viewed individually. I also tried using Global Mapper to convert to .ecw, but this takes several hours to do and is just not very efficient due to the time and the need to use another software. Lastly, I have looked into PostgreSQL, but I do not know if this is portable to other computers.

Any tips on how to store these rasters in order to be able to fit more onto a project hard drive and keep them portable and usable?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. "Best" questions are intrinsically subjective, and "tips" are more discussion-oriented than our Focused question/Best answer model can usually support. While [Chat] could support such a discussion, Chat has a minimum reputation requirement (and probably isn't active enough to generate enough feedback). It seems that the number of rasters is more of a problem than the compression or volume, so maybe you should be focusing on reducing the number of files.

Comment: Compression and convenient storage format are different things. GeoTIFF supports many efficient compression methods https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options but it is one file per image. GeoPackage supports only a handful of compression methods and bit depths https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html. I do not understand the comment about changing extents and losing data. Please clarify. One GeoPackage file can contain however many images, each stored into a separate table but maybe you want to do something else. Are you building an ever growing mosaic of images?

Comment: I found that when adding layers to a geopackage, the set extent of the last layer (whether it be the layer itself or full map extent) tends to be the extent of the full geopackage. I will put in one layer after another and some layers will show up fine when I attempt to bring them in, but others will not render at all or only partially.

Thank you for the links, there is a lot of helpful information in there. and yes, new data will get added every day that data is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the issue with layer extent in GeoPackage. I added three test images into a GeoPackage as three separate layers with gdal_translate first.

```
gdal_translate -of gpkg -co tiling_scheme=googlemapscompatible -co raster_table=test1 test1.tif test.gpkg
gdal_translate -of gpkg -co tiling_scheme=googlemapscompatible -co raster_table=test2 -co append_subdataset=yes test2.tif test.gpkg
gdal_translate -of gpkg -co tiling_scheme=googlemapscompatible -co raster_table=test3 -co append_subdataset=yes test3.tif test.gpkg
```

GDAL sees the three layers as subdatasets. I do not know what the corner coordinates mean when there are subdatasets but the coordinates do not look useful.

```
gdalinfo test.gpkg
Driver: GPKG/GeoPackage
Files: test.gpkg
Size is 512, 512
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=GPKG:test.gpkg:test1
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=test1 - test1
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=GPKG:test.gpkg:test2
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=test2 - test2
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=GPKG:test.gpkg:test3
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=test3 - test3
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

The extents of the subdatasets can be queried individually by using the name of the subdataset

```
gdalinfo GPKG:test.gpkg:test1
...
Metadata:
  IDENTIFIER=test1
  ZOOM_LEVEL=17
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 2370192.944, 9122579.466) ( 21d17'30.50"E, 63d 5'27.31"N)
Lower Left  ( 2370192.944, 9108251.106) ( 21d17'30.50"E, 63d 1'57.39"N)
Upper Right ( 2384501.000, 9122579.466) ( 21d25'13.21"E, 63d 5'27.31"N)
Lower Right ( 2384501.000, 9108251.106) ( 21d25'13.21"E, 63d 1'57.39"N)
Center      ( 2377346.972, 9115415.286) ( 21d21'21.86"E, 63d 3'42.40"N)
```

The extents are stored into the gpkg_contents metadata table individually for each raster table. I do not observe any cumulative effect so that the extent of table test3 would cover also extents of test1 and test2.

[image]